# Saving Overpass query results to GeoJSON file with Python

Tags: python, geojson, export, query, overpass-api

I have just started to use Python and I would like to make a query to Overpass and store the results in a geospatial format (e.g. GeoJSON).

As far as I know, there is a library called `overpy` that should be what I am looking for. After reading [its documentation](https://python-overpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) I came up with the following code:

```py
import overpy

API = overpy.Overpass()

# Fetch highways within Granollers' city.

result = API.query("""
    area[name="Granollers"][admin_level=8];
    // query part for: “highway=*”
    (way["highway"](area);
    relation["highway"](area);
    );
    // print results
    out body;
    """)
```

The thing is that I am not familiar at all with python and I don't know how to store `result` as a GeoJSON file (Honestly, I don't even know what kind of thing `result` is -I tried with `type(result)` and I get `overpy.Result` as an output, which doesn't mean much to my poor knowledge). I have been reading `overpy` documentation but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Same question as also posted here: https://github.com/DinoTools/python-overpy/issues/75 - so better follow up there.

Comment: Yes, it's me who posted it there too. Unfortunately, the question was originally asked months ago without receiving any attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export a valid 'line'-geojson you could set the [verbosity](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper#verbosity) to 'geom'. If you are facing timeout issues you could set a larger [timeout value](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper#timeout) than the default 25.

```py
import overpass
import geojson

api = overpass.API(timeout=500)

# api.get already returns a FeatureCollection, a GeoJSON type
res = api.get("""
    area[name="Granollers"][admin_level=8];
    // query part for: “highway=*”
    (way["highway"](area);
      relation["highway"](area);
    );
""", verbosity='geom')

# dump as file, if you want to save it in file
with open("c:/temp/testio.geojson",mode="w") as f:
  geojson.dump(res,f)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! I love how simple the solution was!

Answer (score 11):

You could do this using [`overpass`](https://pypi.org/project/overpass/) that already returns a `geojson` object and then, if you want, you can use the [`geojson`](https://github.com/jazzband/geojson) package to convert this object into `str` (string object) or save it in a file.

```py
import overpass
import geojson

api = overpass.API()

# api.get already returns a FeatureCollection, a GeoJSON type
res = api.get("""
    area[name="Granollers"][admin_level=8];
    // query part for: “highway=*”
    (way["highway"](area);
      relation["highway"](area);
    );
    // recurse down to get the nodes, required for the geometry
    (._;>;);
""")

# if you want a str, then use dumps function
#geojson_str = geojson.dumps(res)

# dump as file, if you want to save it in file
with open("./test.geo.json",mode="w") as f:
  geojson.dump(res,f)
```

**OBS:** Take a look at the line with `(._;>;);` it is **VERY** important for the example you provide. Your query is about ways and relations, and if you don't add the last line to the query, the server will respond with ways and relations but no nodes and therefore won't be coordinates and without coordinates, the resulting `geojson` won't have geometries at all.

Finally, be aware that this query retrieves almost 2 MB of data, so consider this when you try to handle the results.

Comment: Thank you very much for reviving this issue, @carpinchosaurio!

Comment: I tried your solution after installing osmtogeojson via pip, but I am afraid nor osm2gojson nor json2geojson are defined. Possibly I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Hello again, I am afraid that there is an error on the import statement, which should be `import osm2geojson` (which seems to be a different package than osmtogejson). However, I did not succeed in running the code, as I get some errors `
  File "<ipython-input-1-28700f60e0f8>", line 13, in <module>
    geojson_obj = osm2geojson.json2geojson(res)` amongs others

Comment: I am really sorry @ccamara, you are right my code was wrong, I get confused with some other libraries that I was using for a problem similar to yours, but I fixed this code and tested thoroughly, seems that overpass already returns a geojson so there is no need of osm2geojson anymore, please don't hesitate in asking for any further details, good luck

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. Now it works, except by the fact that it only outputs a regular json, with attributes (OK) but no geometries (KO)

Comment: I have geometries of my points in this example and I can render it into a map, using that geojson, this could be more specific to your case, lets discuss it [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99591/from-overpass-to-gejson-python-ccamara-carpinchosaurio).

Comment: Yes, you are right: your query works fine, but mine -which includes lines, not just nodes- returns no geometry (Even though it should).

Comment: Do you checked the chat where I move the discussion?

Comment: Yes, I have continued it there ;) (I didn't know it existed, though)